# BelongsToMany of Laravel 5.4 does not work

Tags: laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am creating a table where it displays a list of requests, I have a relation between the ID's 'erp_createdid' and 'erp_productid'. To display the name of the products, I created a belongsToMany, in which I specify my two 'ID's'.

**Order model**

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_order';
    protected $fillable = ['erp_createdid'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'erp_orderid';

    public function description()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Description','erp_order_product', 'erp_createdid', 'erp_productid');
    }

}
```

**Description Model**

```
class Description extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_product_description';
    protected $primaryKey = 'erp_productid';
    protected $fillable = ['erp_name'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function order()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'erp_order_product', 'erp_createdid', 'erp_productid');
        }
```

**Table**

```
<td>@foreach($orders->description as $des)
 {{$des->erp_name}}
 @endforeach
 </td>
```

But the values in the table are not displayed, any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the parameters on `Order`'s `belongsToMany` in an incorrect order.

Try this:

```
public function description()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Description','erp_order_product', 'erp_productid', 'erp_createdid');
}
```

Also try updating your foreach like this:

Oh OK, try this:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    @foreach($order->description as $description)
        {{ $description->erp_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more code then? What is in `$orders`?

Comment: $order = Order::orderBy('erp_orderid', 'desc')->paginate(20);

Comment: This is strange, your code is perfect, but the same problem remains, is it because of the databse table?

Comment: Maybe :). Can you give us SQL of DB structure with some data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146208/discussion-between-vinicius-rosa-and-jan).

Comment: You can just update the question here so that other people can see it too.

Comment: Okay! I believe I'm giving error because my createdid is varchar.